# How to upload files into SharePoint Online using Azure DevOps release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sharepoint-online

I have created a build pipeline for the Unity3D project in Azure DevOps. I have successfully generated artifacts for the Unity3D project. I want to upload the artifacts of the Unity3D project into SharePoint Online using the Azure DevOps release pipeline.

So, can anyone suggest to me if there is any release task to upload files into SharePoint Online using the Azure DevOps release pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can upload your artifacts on sharepoint directory. Please find the Azure devops extension which will do the work.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=halliba.az-pipelines-2-sharepoint

This extension is well documented and all the necessary steps are given.

Thanks